# matlab: specify which dimension to index

Tags: matlab

Imagine a function where you want to output a snippet in a user-specified dimension of a n-dimensional matrix

```
function result=a(x,dim)
  window=1:10;
  dim=3;
  result=x(:,:,window);
end
```

How can I put `window` to the desired dimension? E.g. if `dim=2;` then `result=x(:,window,:)`.

The way I can think of right now is to evaluate a string command that puts `window` in the correct position - or use a lot of `if then else` blocks. What's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a cell array to define your indexes, following the examples [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/362211-variable-indexing-for-n-dimension-data).

Specifically, if you have a matrix

```
x = ones(7,5,9);
```

You can define the indexes you want like:

```
% get all the indexes in all dimensions
all_indexes = {':', ':', ':'};

% get all indexes in dimensions 1 and 3, and just indices 1:4 in dimension 2
indexes_2 = {':', 1:4, ':'};
```

And then get those indexes from your matrix `x` like

```
a = x(all_indexes{:});
b = x(indexes_2{:});
```

So, you could write a function like

```
function result=extract_cells(x, dim, window)
  % Create blank cell array {':', ':', ...} with entries ':' for each dimension
  % Edit (c/o Cris Luengo): need to use ndims(x) to get the number of dimensions
  num_dims = ndims(x)
  dims    = cell(1, num_dims);
  dims(:) = {':'};

  % Set the specified window of cells in the specified dimension
  dims{dim} = window;

  % Pick out the required cells
  result=x(dims{:});
end
```

Which could return all the cells in the dimensions other than one specified, and in that direction would return the cells in the range given by `window`. So in the following code, `a` and `b` would be equivalent.

```
a = extract_cells(x, 2, 1:5);
b = x(:, 1:5, :)
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, have updated my original post.